# iBooks disable page scroll animation

Tags: macos, books, epub

I want to disable page scroll animation in iBooks on my Mac when reading epub files. Because it slows down my reading speed and makes my eyes dizzy.  I cannot endure the animation.

PS. I'm happy to accept any other app recommendation for reading epub, but so far i found no epub reader that I liked. iBook notes feature is really nice, so I'd stay with iBook if I can.

Comment: iBooks on Mac or on iOS? Please edit the post to clarify what software you would accept.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the ambiguity. I'm much more interested in how to disable the animation than trying out new apps